# Problema con navbar collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema. Al dar clic a mi botón (hice que desapareciera el menu cuando es chica la pantalla) no me despliega el menu. Llevo rato viendo y revisando la documentación y ejemplos de Bootstrap y no doy con la solución. ¿Alguien tendrá alguna idea para que me oriente?

Dejo el código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Estilos CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .slider {
          background: url(images/slide0.jpg);
          height: 85vh;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>


  <body>

    <!-- Imagen Superior -->
    <section class="container-fluid slider d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <!-- d-flex sirve para alinear elementos uno al lado del otro-->
      <h1 class="display-4">AutoEdifica, un problema una solución!</h1>
    </section>

    <!-- Barra de Navegación -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- Dentro de div para tener margenes -->
      <!-- Barra de bootstrap azul (navbar-inverse bg-inverse) -->
      <!-- navbar-toggleable-md indica hasta cuando queremos que desaparezcan elmentos del menu -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-md">
        <!-- Boton para Responsive, para que despliegue menu hacia abajo -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id01" aria-controls="id01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
          <!-- Logo de la barra se ponen medida porque es img vectorizada -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Logo"> AutoEdifica
          </a>

          <!-- Queremos que cuando la pantalla sea muy chica me siga manteniendo el logo en la barra por eso se coloca el div aqui -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="id01">
            <!-- Se podría poner ul y li o nav-items esta es mas nueva-->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link active">Nosotros</a>
              <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link">Asesorías</a>
              <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link">Preupuestos</a>
              <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link">Contacto</a>
            </div>
          </div>  
      </nav>   
    </div>




    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes la etiqueta que referencia al archivo bootstrap mal formada:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

Cuando deberia de ser:

```
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jajajaj sabes que tambien habia revisado eso y no me percate jajajjajajaja bueno de los errores se aprenden, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Naoto sí la pregunta solucionó su problema por favor marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado. Recuerda marcarla si te funciono.

Comment: @Einer muchas gracias creo que ya la marque como respondida, marcando el chek no ?